# Why is my model unwrapping wrong?

Tags: uv

I made a model of a Sega Mega Drive case, and I want to unwrap the faces to texture it with the label. But the wrap gets distorted. Of course, I can tweak it and make it right but, I still wonder why its not getting unwrapped in a straight line? If I mark seams, it gets divided into 3 parts. I want it to be in 1 part.

[image]
[the blender file](http://www.filedropper.com/landstalkerquestion)

Answer (score 2):

Marking seams is the right way to do it. It got split into three pieces because you marked TOO MANY seams. Think of the model as a paper box that you have to unfold flat. ONLY mark the seams where you'd have to make cuts in order to lay the box flat. Don't mark seams all the way around.

Even still, it might not unwrap straight. You may still have to tweak it a little, but that's why nobody likes UVs ;-) Your most useful tool in this case will be *scale*.
Select a horizontal line of UVs, then type <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> > *0*. That will scale them flat along the Y-axis, making them perfectly horizontal. Then you you can move them up or down. It's tedious, but that's the way it's done.

Comment: Ok thanks for that answer. I get a little confused by the seems but i will try to see if i can find out how to do it without having it split.

Comment: i tried it with seems and had it in one island but it still was not straight, but your tip about "scale" was perfect help. Thanks.